# Colleagues can't connect to external FTP-server

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, ftp, filezilla

Two of my colleagues can't establish a connection to a FTP server via FileZilla. One of them can connect through Dreamviewer, but the other can't connect with none of them. They can ping it.

I can connect without problems from my office. I took my laptop to his office and plugged his lan cable into my laptop and I still can connect to the FTP-server.
So it must be related to a setting on his computer?

He is using a proxy, but it does still fail even after entering the proxy in FileZilla. I also tried disabling the proxy, it made no difference.

Maybe the firewall blocks it? How can I find out if the firewall is the cause?

What might be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to enter the proxy IP and port as servername and put the target servername at the user name by using the @ symbol.

Our username already had a @ symbol in it e.g. `black@ourdomain.com`,
so I had to use this username `black@ourdomain.com@ourdomain.com`

That solved our problem.